# Possible to 'deaden' an asp. net hyperlink?

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink, controls, label

Is there a way for an asp .net hyperlink to behave like a label? i.e. with no url specified and no click event (inc. mouse cursor doesn't change to show it can be clicked)?

Comment: What is it you're trying to do?

Comment: Ofcourse until and unless NavigateUrl property is blank it behaves like a lable.

Comment: @akhil Even if the href/nagivateurl property is blank, the mouse cursor will still change to indicate that it is a clickable link and the control is still rendered out as an `<a>` html tag, so not really.

Comment: @Duane I dont think so. I just double checked it.

Comment: It still get's rendered as an `<a>` tag. Check again...

Comment: but I gues deemac is talking about the asp:Hyperlink control

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a simple hyperlink

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
```

with no navigate url is displayed a lable only.

adding this line to the code behind make it bahave like a Hyperlink

```
HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = "Mypage1.aspx";
```

or set NavigateUrl property of Hyperlink

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Mypage1.aspx">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible. However you could add a javascript onclick event to it that returned false. This should stop the link from firing. You may also be able to change the cursor in css so that it remains a pointer when the mouse passes over the link.

So:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" runat="server" onclick="return false;">Hello</a>
```